# Python Copy Existing File and Increment Name by 1 n Number of Times

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, copy, shutil

I am trying to take an existing file, let's say 0.json that has some code in it.  Then I need to duplicate the file, rename it as 1.json, keep both files and then go through the same process again x number of times incrementing by 1 each time the file is copied.

This is what I tried.  I know this isn't right and incomplete (this code isn't even calling copy or rename)but, I'm just learning 'for loops' at the moment and am getting stuck at each stage.

```
import os
import shutil

#This is getting the current working directory
print(os.getcwd())

#This is changing the directory from above
os.chdir('[INSERT PATH]')

#trying to copy file and then increment the name by +1 each copy and run for a specified range
for file in os.listdir():
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    value = int(name)
    for i in range (0,10):
            i += 1
    new_name = f"{i}{ext}"
```

Comment: So, if your file is named `42.json`, you want to create a new file `43.json` with the same contents?

Comment: @MattDMo yep.  If it was 42 then create a new file called 43 with the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

We looked at the responses above and had a number of issues in some of the return statements from the functions above. Though they did help in setting up a solid framework for the code below. The answer was a blend of getting the directory, parsing the name and extension, incrementing the name (the name of the file was "0.json"; if it were more complex you would need another parser incorporated),

```
#note that this is a Python script that requires a seed file called '0.[extension]'.  For this example
#the file uses a 0.json file

import os
import shutil

dir_path ='[INSERT DIRECTORY inside quotes]' 
n_times = 5  #makes 5 copies

def do_copy(dir_path, n_times):
    assert os.path.exists(dir_path)
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dir_path))
    for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        if not os.path.isfile(file) or file [0] == ".":  # only change names if it's a file or not a .file
            continue
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        print("This is the original file name: ", name)
        start_ind = int(name)
        for n in range(1, n_times+1):
            new_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"{start_ind+n}{ext}")
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file), new_file)

do_copy(dir_path, n_times)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the logic in your `for` loop to increase the file name by 1:

```
for file in os.listdir():
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    value = int(name)
    newname = f"{value + 1}.{ext}"
    shutil.copyfile(file, newname)
```

The file will only be replicated once. When you call `os.listdir()`, it creates a list of files in the current working directory *at that moment*. The code then iterates over that list one by one, taking each file and creating a single copy of it with the filename incremented by 1. Since the newly created files weren't in the directory at the start, they're not added to the list being iterated over. So, for example, say the CWD contains `1.json`, `13.json`, and `42.json`. After the above code runs, it'll contain `1.json`, `2.json`, `13.json`, `14.json`, `42.json`, and `43.json`.

---

Your new requirement is to create 10,000 identical files from one input file. Here's how to do that:

```
for file in os.listdir():
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    value = int(name)
    for i in range(value+1, value+10001):
        newname = f"{i}.{ext}"
        shutil.copyfile(file, newname)
```

Comment: So how would I limit the increments to make sure it stops after 100 times or some other defined amount?  I can't figure out how to nest a range in here.

Comment: Why do you need a range? Are you copying `42.json` to `43.json`, `44.json`, `45.json`, etc? I don't understand what needs to stop.

Comment: I specifically need 10000 copies of this file because it contains metadata and I need a unique meta file for each iteration with a corresponding file name.  So I want to be able to say "make 10K copies of this file and increment the name by 1 each time".  But I only want 10K iterations.  No more and no less.

Comment: So there's only 1 file in the directory at the start?

Comment: That's right.  I created the meta file with all it's necessary descriptors as a seed.

Comment: OK, now see my update. Information like this needs to be in the original question.

Comment: That info was in the original question, and in the original code

Comment: @TheLazyScripter True, but it wasn't very clear, at least to me. The response to my comment below the question led me to think the OP only needed a single copy of multiple files. But, either way, we both eventually arrived at the same answer, yours just has more error checking. I didn't include that in mine because I figured this is a one-off script and the files and directories are known, but I suppose you shouldn't assume that. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Should be obvious but make a backup prior to running any of these answers. Also should be stated that if you ran this more than once, then it would make a new copy for each of the `n` files in the directory. Most would be overwritten, by a new file, but you would end up with 'n' more per run, starting from the last index. So only run it once!

```
def do_copy(root, n_times):
    assert os.path.exists(root)
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), root))
    for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        if not os.path.isfile(file):  # only change names if it's a file
            continue
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        start_ind = int(name)
        for n in range(1, n_times):
            new_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"{start_ind+n}{ext}")
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file), new_file)


do_copy("so_help\\A", 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the warning and for the code example.  Will make sure that this is only run once and will test on a small number of copies.  Given that I'm a total newbie to both stack overflow and to python, is it appropriate to ask what the "so_help\\A", 2 is doing inside of the do_copy?

Comment: that's just the location I used for testing. So that would be your file directory relative to your script. So for me my script is located at `"C:\Users\MyName\PycharmProjects\pythonProject"` and the directory is located at `"so_help\\a\\0.txt"` in the same directory.

Comment: Okay thanks.  That is helpful.  And the ',2' was applied to the "n_times"?  Essentially root = so_help\\a\\0 and n_times = 2?

Comment: Correct, so that would be the number of copies you want.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give this a try later and see if that gets things moving.  What is the best way to cite you if this is the right solution?  I may post this in my github.